# Is it possible to merge in a SELECT in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, merge

Let's say I want to retrieve 100 records from a table called `messages`, and I want to obtain them the following way:

```
1st message
100th message
2nd message
99th message
3rd message
98th message
(...)
```

Is there any way to do this *efficiently*? What would be the appropriate query?
Or should I make a query to select the first 50, a query to select the last 50 and then merge the results?

Comment: This is one case where I would probably make two queries and merge them in application code. It can probably be done in one query by creating row numbers and using a very clever conditional `ORDER BY`, but would be a lot easier to do in application code.

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same... Probably it's easier/more efficient to do it with two different queries and merge their results in the code

Comment: I would definitely wait to see if someone here can produce an ingenious solution. There are some pretty clever folks around here.

Comment: do you know the number of records that you want to retrieve in advance ? is it always 100 ?

Comment: please include the ORDER logic, always order by add_date desc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try if your ID is a sequence of numbers:

First

```
SET @half = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages)/2;
```

Then

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` ORDER BY (IF(id<@half,@half*2-id,id-1)) DESC,id ASC;
```

Comment: The `ASC` at the end, should be `DESC`. Aside from that, this works perfectly and it's the simplest solution of all these. Thanks!

Comment: A bit too late to ask... but what if, instead of orderning by `id` I'm ordering by `timestamp` (using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)`)?

Comment: Will not work, the order are based on even and odd ID numbers and the timestamp not is linear to adapt it...

Answer (score 0):

The point is to create two virtual columns "serie_order" (variant) and "serie" (constant) you'll use on both parts of your data (you'll have to split your data in two).

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 as serie, message_id AS serie_order , *  FROM
   (SELECT message_id FROM messages ) as part_up
UNION 
  SELECT 2 as serie, 101-message_id  as serie_order, * FROM
   (SELECT message_id FROM messages) as part_down
) AS world

ORDER BY serie_order ASC, serie ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Sadly MySQL lacks a `generate_series()` function.

Comment: That was just used as virtual data, i edited using the op "messages" table

Comment: This is the right idea but not quite correct.  The bare "*" needs to come first in SELECTs, otherwise it's a syntax error.  Separately, what if "messages" has, say, 200 rows?  As an aside, you don't need the innermost derived tables, as you could simply `SELECT 1 AS serie, message_id AS serie_order, message_id FROM messages`.

Comment: You're totally right (and i should have been tired to write that :p)

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 as serie, message_id AS serie_order , *  FROM messages
) as part_up
UNION 
  SELECT 2 as serie, - message_id  as serie_order, * FROM messages
) as part_down

) AS world

ORDER BY serie_order ASC, serie ASC

Answer (score 0):

```
set @rank:=0; 

select id from 
(select id, @rank:=(coalesce(@rank, 0)+1) as new_order 
 from a_table 
 order by some_column limit 100) as ordering
order by if (new_order<=50, new_order-1, abs(100-new_order)) asc;
```

Comment: Almost!  "new_order" 1 and "new_order" 100 both become 0 in your ORDER BY clause, and 2 and 99 become 1, etc.  How does MySQL know which record to put first?  You need a second ORDER BY criteria, as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8371930/132382), to guarantee the proper output.